Partial testing with Vitest
I want to run only some of my test files but not all, it is possible to do it ?
For example I want to run only tests that is inside /test/vue-components/ folder, how can I do it?

https://vitest.dev/guide/cli.html#vitest

I found out that it can be done with filtering feature which work for folders too.
So for my case the command was:
vitest vue-components

https://vitest.dev/guide/filtering.html

use the -t, --testNamePattern  option to filter tests by full name. This can be helpful when you want to filter by the name defined within a file rather than the filename itself.
reference link: https://vitest.dev/guide/filtering
